# Dart, creating variable scope section to use the same name variable multiple times

Tags: dart

In my project, I have a code like this (very simplified):

```
void main() async {
  int times2({required int integer}) {
    return integer*2;
  }
  
  final t1 = 0;
  print(times2(integer: t1));

  final t2 = 10;
  print(times2(integer: t2));

  final t3 = 25;
  print(times2(integer: t3));
}
```

So here is the issue with this code. This part of the code is likely to change in the future. I might want to add the situation where the integer is 15. I can either:

```
void main() async {
  int times2({required int integer}) {
    return integer*2;
  }
  
  final t1 = 0;
  print(times2(integer: t1));

  final t2 = 10;
  print(times2(integer: t2));

  final t3 = 15;
  print(times2(integer: t3));

  final t4 = 25;
  print(times2(integer: t4));
}
```

or

```
void main() async {
  int times2({required int integer}) {
    return integer*2;
  }
  
  final t1 = 0;
  print(times2(integer: t1));

  final t2 = 10;
  print(times2(integer: t2));

  final t2_1 = 15;
  print(times2(integer: t2_1));

  final t3 = 25;
  print(times2(integer: t3));
}
```

In both cases, it can lead to confusion (because of the naming.)

I found one solution that can prevent this.

```
void main() async {
  int times2({required int integer}) {
    return integer*2;
  }
  
  () {
    final t = 0;
    print(times2(integer: t));
  }();
  
  () {
    final t = 1;
    print(times2(integer: t));
  }();
  
  () {
    final t = 2;
    print(times2(integer: t));
  }();
}
```

It feels so wrong writing like this. My questions are, "Are there problems writing a code like this?" or "Do we have a better way to achieve this?".

additional note:
I can create a named function for this simplified code but the actual code can't be done with a named function(it will make it more complicated).

```
void newFunction({required int integer}) { // Don't want to create a function
  print(times2(integer: integer));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you have repeating code you should create function or loop.**

Loop example:

```dart
int times2({required int integer}) {
  return integer*2;
}

for(final t in <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) {
  print(times2(integer: t));
}
```

**Edit according to conversation in comments.**

This is how I do unit test:

```dart
void main() {
  void main() {
  MyClassAdapter().registerForId(1);

  group('Test serializing', () {
    group('integers', () {
      test('Uint8', () {
        const data = 126;
        final expected = [127, 255, 126];
        expect(
          binary.serialize(data), 
          equals(expected),
        );
      });
      test('Int8', () { 
        const data = -14;
        final expected = [127, 254, 242];
        
        expect(
          binary.serialize(data), 
          equals(expected),
        );
      });
    ...

}
```

Comment: sadly it's not a repeated code. The only thing that is common are the integer t, and the section that calls the times2 function. The actual code contains very different processing code parts. This is why I can't create a named function...

Comment: @YukinosukeTakada seems like a bad code design xd. Split large function in small functions.

Comment: the actual code is a unit test... So what I'm doing is testing a single function for many situations/conditions.

Comment: do each test inside a `test` method. I will edit answer.

Comment: Yes, That is the exact thing I want to achive but I’m using blocTest which is supposes to be used by itself not with test…

Comment: Sorry I can't help you blocTest seems to confusing to me :(

Comment: That's understandable, appreciate your response.